# how do I make to recognize the body of the robot, as blender recognize just the body?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, modifiers, mirror

I tried to create a very simple robot. I started with a cube as head and then I extrude the neck and the rest of the body. I used the mirror modifier. But when I put a plane under the robot and I  press P, the robot is falling until the head meets the floor, not until the legs meets it. Floor is a static and the robot is a character.

Comment: it has to do with the bounding box of your robot, maybe you should ctrl+a and 'apply' visual transform'

Comment: Try Ctrl+A and then rotation and scale.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can enable `Main Menu/Game/Show Physics Visualization`. It allows you to see the physics mesh while running the game.

[image]

When you use the mesh object as presentation object and as physics object - ensure to select the right `Physics/Collision Bounds/Bounds`.

When you use one of the primitive collision shapes (box, cylinder ...) the mesh should be symmetrical around the origin. This means the origin should be in the middle of the object. According to your description, this is not your current situation.

Example:

[image]

The origin of this mesh is not in the vertical middle. With the primitive shapes the mesh will be out of the bounding box and out of shape:

[image]

When you use detailed shapes the origin does not need to be at the middle. But they need much more processing power:

[image]

In all cases the origin should be inside the bounding box of the mesh. Otherwise the physics might calculate results you do not expect.